# Excel Power Query > Add columns from another table

Tags: excel, append, powerquery

Need some guidance, please. I have two power query tables in excel, I'm looking to add columns from table B to table A where the Customer# matches. I don't want to use vlookup formulas due to performance so I was wondering if with power query this is possible.

Here is an example:

[image: Here is an example:]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is possible by merging the tables. Maybe [this](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/10/28/merge-data-based-on-two-columns/) helps.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to write code in SQL Server to join the data from both tables and insert [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usOze.png)

Answer (score 0):

The M-Code for merging TableA with TableB would look like that

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],
    chgType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer Number", type text}, {"Certification", type text}}),
    mergeQueries = Table.NestedJoin(chgType, {"Customer Number"}, TableB, {"Customer Number"}, "TableB", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    extendTbl = Table.ExpandTableColumn(mergeQueries, "TableB", {"Crd Limit"}, {"Crd Limit"})
in
    extendTbl
```

You need to import TableB into Powerquery beforehand, as well.

Further reading on this

[Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9)

[Excel Guru Blog](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/10/28/merge-data-based-on-two-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want by to a `JoinKind.Inner`.

*Note that this will return customer ID's that are present in both tables. If that is not the case, and you want unmatched ID's to be returned, you'll need to do a `.NestedJoin` with `JoinKind.FullOuter` and then expand the resulting table.*

eg:

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],
    tabA = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{{"Customer Number", type text}, {"Certification", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableB"]}[Content],
    tabB = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Customer Number", type text}, {"Crd Limit", Currency.Type}}),
    joinTbl = Table.Join(tabA,"Customer Number",tabB,"Customer Number",JoinKind.Inner)
in 
    joinTbl
```

[image]